# What is rms power generated in an LC circuit?

Tags: capacitor, inductance

LC CIRCUIT without ac supply. What is rms power generated or is it generated?

Comment: No idea what you're asking. Please clarify your question adding diagrams or schematics as necessary.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please edit your question. Add a schematic of the circuit, explain what exactly do you want and write your attempt of solving the question. Without showing effort, you will not get help.

Comment: What is "rms power"?

Answer (score 2):

An inductor can store energy. A capacitor can store energy. No power is being generated. If the components are ideal, they can store the energy indefinitely, with no losses. In the inductor it's \$E=0.5LI^2\$ and for the capacitor it's \$E=0.5CV^2\$.

In a resonating LC circuit, they exchange energy between them. No power is being generated. Of necessity, each stores the same energy. This means if you know three of the L, C, peak I and peak V, you can calculate the fourth.

You can calculate a mean power (rate of transfer of energy) by which the energy of one gets transferred to the other as (the amount of energy)/(the transfer time). The resonant frequency of an L and C is \$f_{HZ}=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$, from which it's easy to calculate the transfer time as half of a cycle.